# Grouping data then appending together using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I have a dataframe (base_varlist3) which has all character variables. I'd like to loop through each of these character variables (this is the operator k) and append to an empty dataset, which has the columns 'Variable','Dist_Val','value'

```
In [217]: output_nvd = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Variable','Dist_Val','value'])
     ...: print(output_nvd)
     ...: 
     ...: #for k in range(0,4):
     ...: #for k in range(0,len(varlist3)):    
     ...: k=4
     ...: 
     ...: nvd_var = varlist3[k]
     ...: print('NVD transform variable: ' + nvd_var)
     ...: 
     ...: output_nvd_temp = base_varlist3.groupby(nvd_var)[nvd_var].count()
     ...: 
     ...: output_nvd = output_nvd.append(output_nvd_temp)
     ...: 
     ...: print(output_nvd)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Variable, Dist_Val, value]
Index: []
NVD transform variable: WATCHLIST_CATEGORY_CODE
                        Variable Dist_Val value         .       1       2  \
WATCHLIST_CATEGORY_CODE      NaN      NaN   NaN  271671.0  1108.0  2167.0   

                             3  
WATCHLIST_CATEGORY_CODE  621.0
```

In the example above, I've manually changed k to 4 which means the variable to transform is WATCHLIST_CATEGORY_CODE. This has distinct values of:
`.`,`1` and `2`. I want these values to be counted and added to the bottom of my empty dataset... but I want the column name to appear under `Variable`, and the distinct values to appear transformed under `Dist_Val`, with the count of each distinct value appearing in the `value` column.

So I want this:

```
Variable                     Dist_Val   value         
WATCHLIST_CATEGORY_CODE      .          271671.0
WATCHLIST_CATEGORY_CODE      1          1108.0
WATCHLIST_CATEGORY_CODE      2          2167.0
```

I know I need a `pd_melt` but I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing it. I've tried this but I couldn't figure out what my `id_vars` should be:

`output_nvd_temp2=pd.melt(output_nvd_temp, id_vars='Obs_Date', value_vars=varlist4)`

Oh and in the case that `output_nvd_temp` is an empty dataframe, I don't want it to append at all, but I don't want my code to error.

Apologies, Python noob here. Would be good to get some advice from the pros on how to do this in the most Pythonic way.

Comment: I'm not following this question. Can you reword it to be more clear? Can you show sample all of your starting dataframes?

Comment: My `groupby.count()` creates the output I need, but not in the correct format. The class variable is arranged in columns, but I want them in rows, then I want to append them to my empty dataframe to create the one above.